# comparing two different kinds of lists in python and getting index

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare two lists in python and getting index. But the 2 lists are in different form.

```
list1:

[array(['apple'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['tim', 'out', 'over'], 
       dtype='<U32')array(['orange', 'oop'], 
       dtype='<U32'), , array(['senty', 'analys'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['context', 'analys'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['mis', 'report'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['man', 'wom'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['hospit', 'man', 'solv'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['big', 'dat', 'platform'], 
       dtype='<U32'), array(['hi', 'all'], 
       dtype='<U32'),  array(['analys'], 
       dtype='<U32')]


list2: 

['proact','man','apple',
 'stat','intellig',
 'algorithm','hol','hi','solv']
```

I have to check if any of the elements in  `list2` is present in `list1` (with out unlisting `list1`)and the corresponding index of `list1`. Eg: in `list2` is present in `list1` at 6th position. `list1[6]=['man','wom']`. so i have to get the index `6`. similary for all elements. In this example it should return [0,6,9] . Because apple ,man, and hi is there in list2. so it should return the corresponding positions in list1.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `list2` to a set first for more efficient lookups, use `enumerate` to generate indices for the arrays in `list1`, then test the items in the arrays to see if any of them is in the set, and output the indices of those that are (using `next` to get just the first one here):

```
set2 = set(list2)
index = next(i for i, a in enumerate(list1) for s in a if s in set2)
```

Comment: :but this index value returns zero . why?

Comment: I just tested it myself and I got `6`.

Comment: But in this eg. it should return [0,6,9] . Because apple ,man, and hi is there in list2. so it should return the corresponding positions in list1.

Comment: Ah, this is because in your question you are missing a comma between `'apple'` and `'stat'` in your `list2` definition, so Python would treat them as one string `'applestat'`. With the comma added, it would return `[0, 6, 7, 7, 9]` if you replace `next` with `list`.